# Hybris source code on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

There are a lot of Hybris specific classes I have been using in the past years like:

```
UserService, SessionService, ModelService, ModelContext, CmdImpExService, FlexibleSearchService
```

I noticed that these classes are present in jar files ( e.g ***coreserver.jar*** ) and Intellij can easily decompile them.

I am interested in the associated **.java** files because I want to see all the javadoc and because I want to make the debug process a lot easier.
I also know that the .java files depend on the Hybris version.

Is there any set of steps(or any link) I can follow so that I can get the source(.java) files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, hybris is very protective of their source code. But you can get JavaDoc here:

https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/api/commercesuite/index.html

However you need a hybris account for access. Replace 6.2.0 with whatever version you use.

There are also plugins for IntelliJ available at:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525-hybris-integration (paid)
- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12639-integration-for-sap-commerce/ (free)

When you import your project using this plugin, it automatically adds the JavaDoc to your projects.

Comment: Hybris integration plugin is not free.

Comment: Yes, it was changed to a paid version recently. There is an alternative here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12639-integration-for-sap-commerce/